# Transpose row to new column based on cell value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I am currently trying to take a row and transpose it into another sheet if the word in column E says "catering". I can't seem to figure out how to get the formula to grab the current row and I am wondering if I am going to have to write an app script instead. I have tried and IF statement with TRANSPOSE to no avail. I have tried running a query and that hasn't helped either.

To be clear I want the formula to see if column E says catering and if it does then it takes the row with the word catering and transposes it vertically into sheet2. If empty fields could be eliminated on transfer that would be even better.

Here is an example of the sheet I am working with.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C6cPwtg0CZVfhjZm3KIxGJzcQaOfWCNXMWSKOei-zx0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!1:996, "where E is not null and E = 'Catering' order by A", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I get a parse error

Comment: @KodyMoreno answer updated. try now

Answer (score 0):

While your are using criteria `Catering` then you no need use `is not null`. What do you mean by transpose? Try-

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!1:996, "Select * Where E = 'Catering' Order by A",1)
```